# NodeMCU esp8266 idea on how to overlap animations on LED-matrix

Tags: c++, animation, matrix, arduino, esp8266

Up front, I am a beginner in microcontrollers and the language.

I have an 11 by 10 LED matrix, and I wrote some code that sends a pulse from the center to the edges over 1 second. I use a 270-degree circle to have the pulse start in the middle and light up the next LED once it is on maximum brightness. The offset over the board is 90Degree meaning when the pulse is at the Edges the center is dark again, so spreading like a ring.

Yes, I know I could restart the pulse by going for a 180-degree cycle and with modulo on the time instead of restarting one timeframe again.

But what I want is potentially have an audio input that reacts to music and to random times leading to overlapping pulses.

I need help with an idea for a solution here.

My current thought is to create an array size 10, holding up to 10 pulse start timers, and then instead of looping over one, I loop over all of them, calculate the current brightness for RGB for all pulses per LED, and then set the LED values to the median of all those states.

The question is tho, is there a better solution, or am I on an entirely wrong approach all along? And does this particular controller have a solution for asynchronous code, meaning I could instead of current brightness, only calculate deltas, and then I don't have to calculate a median and can just add all the deltas together immediately.

Here my current code:

```cpp
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LED_PIN D4        // Pin connected to the LED
#define LED_COUNT 150     // Total number of LEDs
#define MATRIX_WIDTH 11   // Width of the LED matrix
#define MATRIX_HEIGHT 10  // Height of the LED matrix
#define PULSE_TIME 1500   // Time in milliseconds for the pulse effect

CRGB leds[LED_COUNT];
const int matrixLEDCount = MATRIX_WIDTH * MATRIX_HEIGHT;
float brightnessValues[matrixLEDCount];
int mappedMatrix[matrixLEDCount] = {...}; // custom LED's do not match up with the matrix so it is mapped, irrelevant for funcitonality
int center_x = (MATRIX_WIDTH - 1) / 2;
int center_y = (MATRIX_HEIGHT - 1) / 2;
float maxDistance = sqrt(pow(center_x, 2) + pow(center_y, 2));  // 7-ish

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN>(leds, LED_COUNT);
  FastLED.setBrightness(50);  // Adjust overall brightness if needed
  FastLED.clear(true);
}

unsigned long pulseInterval = millis();
unsigned long pulseStart = millis();
unsigned long pulseRateTime = millis();

void loop() {
  if (millis() - pulseInterval <= PULSE_TIME) {// Ignore this duplicate for now, it is to potentially start the pulse at different rates
    if (millis() - pulseStart <= PULSE_TIME) {
      if (millis() - pulseRateTime >= 30) {
        pulseRateTime = millis();

        float pulseProgress = float(millis() - pulseStart) / PULSE_TIME;  // %

        // Calculate brightness for each LED based on its distance from the center
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixLEDCount; i++) {
          int x = i % MATRIX_WIDTH;
          int y = i / MATRIX_WIDTH;

          float distance = sqrt(pow(x - center_x, 2) + pow(y - center_y, 2));
          float brightnessOffset = (distance / (maxDistance + 1));  // %
          if (brightnessOffset > pulseProgress) {
            leds[mappedMatrix[i]] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
            continue;
          }

          float fadeDegree = (pulseProgress * 270.0) - (90 * brightnessOffset); // Edge to center should be exact opposites
          int brightness = sin(fadeDegree * (3.14159 / 180.0)) * 255;

          // Preventing the restart so all LED's go off
          if(brightness <0){
            brightnessValues[i]; // In case this becomes relevant in overlapping pulses
            leds[mappedMatrix[i]] = CRGB(0, 0, 0);
            continue;
          }
          brightnessValues[i] = brightness;
          leds[mappedMatrix[i]] = CRGB(0, 0, brightnessValues[i]);
        }
        FastLED.show();
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Resetting
    pulseInterval = millis();
    pulseStart = millis();
  }
}
```